# Cannot change keyboard layout when using citrix receiver on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, keyboard, keyboard-layout, citrix

I use Fedora 25 and use citrix receiver to connect to my job windows session.
When I log on to windows the keyboard layout is messed up, it appears keystrokes sent are from an US keyboard and I am using a UK keyboard.

I tried to adjust settings in `~/.ICAClient/wfclient.ini` with no luck

```
[WFClient]                                                                                          
Version = 2                                                                                         
KeyboardLayout = (Server Default)        //this                                                            
KeyboardMappingFile = automatic.kbd                                                                 
KeyboardDescription = (Server Default) //this                                                             
KeyboardType = (Server Default)           //this
```

Anyone know how to change the settings ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with keyboard in Spanish (with catalan variations) and Linux Mint in English (US variation).

Changing `KeyboardLayout= Spanish` in `wfclient.ini`  helped me.

In your case, try with `KeyboardLayout= British` or `KeyboardLayout= United Kingdom`

Comment: @dr01, you have edited my answer. While you have let the same meaning of it, you have corrected some style/layout. I'm new here so I kindly accept any clarification or any style pointer that you can provide.

Comment: Hi @ferranm and welcome to U&L.  Not a big deal: your answer was quite good, and I just removed a bit at the end (additions like "Thanks", "Hope this helps", etc. are seen as noise here), and the quotes around the filename which didn't made sense.  I also changed the formatting to make it a bit more readable (IMHO).   Here are some discussions on Meta about editing posts: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing .  You can also click on "edited X days ago" on any edited post to see how it was changed and get a gist of the guidelines about writing on this site.

Comment: Thanks @dr01 (I hope this is allow in cooments ;-) I will read the links you point to.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried without success:

```
KeyboardLayout= Spanish
```

It work's with capital letters:

```
KeyboardLayout= SPANISH
```

Thanks for @ferranm for you answer it guided me.

Pd: tested on
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.50-v7+ #896 SMP Thu Jun 20 16:11:44 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux